# rvest help: webscraping empty results

Tags: r, rvest

I need a help with my webscraping.... can someone save me?

I am trying to get the list of universities in this webpage https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php for this purpose, I am using the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)


whed_afg <- "https://www.whed.net/results_institutions.php"
whed_afg1 <- read_html(whed_afg)
whed_afg1
str(whed_afg1)

univ_afg1 = whed_afg1 %>% html_nodes("#results .fancybox\\.iframe") %>% html_text()
univ_afg1
```

I put double "" on the html_nodes because it was giving me error: Error: '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""#results .fancybox."

Can someone help me, I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you all,
Ricardo

Comment: I think that you should you RSelenium. 
What is the output that you need?

Comment: Dear Earl, Thank you for your help. What I am trying to get is the list of the name of universities from this webpage.  Like:   University A, University B, University C,... in each row. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you have the wrong start url? Or it is behind a login as I get re-directed with your url. I see a full university list on the following url and with a different class for selecting. These could be split by country of interest.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.iau-aiu.net/List-of-IAU-Members?lang=en"
universities <- read_html(url)  %>% html_nodes('.spip_out') %>% html_text()
print(universities)
```